# How to handle more steps form?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm creating plugin in Wordpress with more steps form, and I would like to take some advice from you.

I've one function (using shortcode) with first form, after submit, I'd like to go on next step, but I don't know which solution is the best

My function:

```
function task_shortcode(){ ?>
    <form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Add new task</h3>
        <div class="task-title">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="text" name="text">
        </div>
        <div class="task-description">
            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea id="desc" name="desc"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="task-new">
            <input type="submit" id="create-task" name="create_new_task" value="Create new task">
        </div>
    </form>
<?php
}
add_shortcode('task_site','task_shortcode');
```

After that I want to go to another form and I dont know how to handle it. Using classic php action on submit button, or is there another solution?

I've found this, but I don't know if I can use it, because I want it to use on frontend.
https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/

Thanks for every advice